# Center an Image Vertically inside a div in Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to align images vertical inside card in Materialize. I have also use a custom slider called **xlider** inside the card. The images are horizontally centered, but not vertically.

```
.custom{
  width: 350px;  /*Used in (1), This is done so the column doesn't change shapes through out any screen*/
}

.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  user-select: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  display: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
 right:0;
}

@media (hover: hover){
.card:hover .prev,
.card:hover .next{
  display: block;
}
}

.xlider {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.xlide {
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: inherit;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.xlide img {
margin:auto;
position: absolute;
object-fit: contain;
max-height:100%;
align-items: center;
}

    <div class="col custom">
        <div class="card" >
            <div class="card-image grey lighten-3" style="height: 245px; position: relative;overflow: hidden; ">
              <div class="xlider">    
                 <div class="xlide"><img src="https://images.craigslist.org/00505_dRUnpYQSFVu_300x300.jpg" ></div>
                 <div class="xlide"><img src="https://images.craigslist.org/00s0s_eCSJ00mPdFU_300x300.jpg" ></div>
                 <div class="xlide"><img src="https://images.craigslist.org/00p0p_6neNmaCByuU_300x300.jpg" ></div>
                 <div class="xlide"><img src="https://images.craigslist.org/00n0n_8uRrQ143Bdz_300x300.jpg" ></div>
                 <div class="xlide"><img src="https://images.craigslist.org/00J0J_bd1qKahXbwH_300x300.jpg" ></div>

              </div>
              <a class="prev" onclick="goLeft(this)">&#10094;</a>
              <a class="next" onclick="goRight(this)">&#10095;</a>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried putting verticle-align, align-item, margin-top. and so far all of these have failed.

A live version of the code is here:

https://jsbin.com/mapesidasu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Make some changes to your CSS. try this :

```
.xlider {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.xlide img {
object-fit: contain;
height:100%;
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Wow, works like a charm! thanks! But just to understand why that happaned, is it because of that max-height declaration? Should I avoid max-height?

Comment: You're very welcome, as matter of fact when you try to use a max-height on element like this because it is smaller that it's parent, it tries to fit the parent element in vertical axis and for images that are not vertical causes this kinda problems.